# RxJs - Check localStorage for cached value and silently fetch data from api

Tags: angular, rxjs

Looking for some guidance from any RxJs wizards out there.

In my app I have some dropdown service with an Observable object like so:

```
  readonly siteDdlState$: Observable<HttpRequestState<CommonWebResponse<Dropdown[]>>> = this._refreshSiteDdl$.pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      this._http.get<CommonWebResponse<Dropdown[]>>(API_PATHS.siteDropdown())
        .pipe(
          httpRequestStates(),
          tap((state: HttpRequestState<CommonWebResponse<Dropdown[]>>) => {
            this._toast.onStateChange(state, true);
          })
        )
    ),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

I subscribe to this observable from a route resolver that looks like this:

```
export class SiteDdlResolver implements Resolve<Observable<HttpRequestState<CommonWebResponse<Dropdown[]>> | undefined>> {
  siteDdl$ = new ReplaySubject<HttpRequestState<CommonWebResponse<Dropdown[]>>>(1);

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private dropdownService: DropdownService,
    private logger: LogService
  ) {
    this.dropdownService.siteDdlState$
      .subscribe({
        next: (value: HttpRequestState<CommonWebResponse<Dropdown[]>>) => this.siteDdl$.next(value),
        error: (error) => this.logger.error('Error resolving site dropdown.', error)
    });
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Observable<HttpRequestState<CommonWebResponse<Dropdown[]>>>> {
    return of(this.siteDdl$);
  }
}
```

This allows me to do the following in my dropdown html template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="ddlData$ | async as ddlData; else noDataMessage">
  <ng-container *ngIf="ddlData?.isLoading; then loadingSpinner"></ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="ddlData?.error; then errorMessage"></ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="(!ddlData?.value?.data || !ddlData?.value?.data?.length) && (!ddlData?.isLoading && !ddlData?.error); then noDataMessage"></ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="ddlData?.value?.data?.length; then formControl"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

This observable calls and AWS Lambda api to get data. If the lambda is cold, it can take several seconds for the data to return. Rather than using `shareReplay(1)` I would like to pull from local storage.

So, I am stuck wrapping my head around how I could modify this observable to instead:

- Check local storage for a cached value
- If value found, return it in the same `Observable<HttpRequestState<CommonWebResponse<Dropdown[]>>>` format
- Also, if value found, silently fetch new data, without triggering loading states, to see if the cache needs to be updated
- If not found, default to calling the Lambda api.

Im still learning RxJs so any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What should happen if you find a value in the cache and the *silent* API returns a new value, i.e. a value different from what is in the cache?

Comment: @Picci See my answer below for more detail, but at the moment the silent API call will update the cached value upon success. So, there is the possibility that users could see outdated cached values, but its not a major concern as this particular data is very static and rarely changes. If i apply this to less static requests i would likely implement a notification that would show they are seeing cached data with a timestamp of when it was last updated/refreshed and if there is a newer value.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `iif` operator. Instead of `httpRequestStates()`

```
iif(cacheHasValue, of(cacheValue), httpRequestStates())
```

Comment: I will look into `iif` but I use the `httpRequestStates` for all http requests. It wraps the requests in a nice Type giving me `{value: T, error: HttpErrorResponse, isLoading: boolean}`

Comment: Then put the cache management logic into the httpRequestStates function.

Comment: `httpRequestStates()` is not a function i wrote or control. It is a library I am using from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-http-request-state

Comment: Then wrap it in your own function that hides the caching implementation from the components

Answer (score 0):

The solution I settled on that allowed me to keep everything as is without changing my html templates was like so.

Instead of trying to create some complex single observable to fetch from cache or http and update cache, i just made two observables in my service:

Fetch from HTTP and update cache on complete:

```
  readonly siteDdlHttp$: Observable<HttpRequestState<CommonWebResponse<Dropdown[]>>> =
    this._http.get<CommonWebResponse<Dropdown[]>>(API_PATHS.siteDropdown())
      .pipe(
        httpRequestStates(),
        tap(state => {
          this.toastStateChange(state);
          this.cacheStateChange(state);
        }),
      );
```

Fetch from cache and mimick http request state:

```
  readonly siteDdlCache$: Observable<HttpRequestState<CommonWebResponse<Dropdown[]>>> =
    this._cache.getItem$('siteDdl')
      .pipe(
        httpRequestStates()
      );
```

Then in my route resolver, combine the two observable into one:

```
this.dropdownService.siteDdlCache$.pipe(
  combineLatestWith(this.dropdownService.siteDdlHttp$),
  map(([ddlCache, ddlHttp]) => ddlCache ? ddlCache : ddlHttp)
).subscribe({
  next: (value) => this.siteDdl$.next(value),
  error: (error) => this.logger.error('Error resolving site dropdown.', error)
});
```

What this does now is check the cache for value first, if it exists return it immediately, but also asynchronously make http call to fetch the data from backend which will update the cache on return. This also solves my problem of not triggering loading states when there is cached value to use.

The one caveat I will need to figure out at a later time is that if there is newer data returned from the http call, then i need to either update the dropdown values in real time, or provide some kind of alert that there is updated cached data. But, im happy with this solution for the moment.

If anyone has any further suggestions for improvements please post them.